# Vim: is it possible to add a modeline for :syntax sync fromstart in a file?

Tags: vim, sync, syntax, modeline

I'm writing a really long page to document a compiler and I was thinking that it would be nice if the doxygen highlighting would stick around. Only if I do a search to further down the file, it loses track since the number of line in that one comment is really large (1066 right now).

I have found that you could tell the system to synchronize from the start of the file using:

```
:syntax sync fromstart
```

Which works great. Now I was wondering whether I could have that (or maybe define the number of lines?) in the modeline info so that way it works as is each time I open the file.

I also noticed the minlines, but that's also something specific to the syntax and it does not look like I can just write:

```
vim: minlines=10000
```

This is viewed as an error.

Comment: You can only have `set` commands in a modeline.

Comment: Yeah... and I was thinking that the `minlines` and `fromstart` were no `set` commands... too bad.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for is what's known in Vimscript as an `autocmd` on a `BufEnter` event.  Adding the following line to your `.vimrc` will execute the desired command for each file you open:

`autocmd BufEnter * :syntax sync fromstart`

If you only want to open on certain file extensions, just replace the `*` above with a more specific pattern for the file name, like `*.at` or somesuch.  If you're still losing your highlighting, you could also trigger the autocommand on some other event like [entering Insert mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#InsertEnter).

There's a lot you can do with these autocommand-event pairs.  If you're interested in learning a bit more about them, I would also recommend reading over a few paragraphs of this [online guide](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html).  For the sake of clarity, or for those that come after you, here's a great visual shorthand from this guide:

```
:autocmd BufNewFile * :write
         ^          ^ ^
         |          | |
         |          | The command to run.
         |          |
         |          A "pattern" to filter the event.
         |
         The "event" to watch for.
```

The above is an example of an autocommand that would automatically save a file whenever you enter a command like `vim newfile` from the command line.